# Objective-C/ALAssetslibrary - How retrieve the correct path of the assets

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary

I have implemented a simple method that find the path of the images inside the device. Actually i'm using the iPhone Simulator. This is the code that i'm using:

```
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if (asset){
                NSString *description = [asset description];
                NSRange first = [description rangeOfString:@"URLs:"];
                NSRange second = [description rangeOfString:@"?id="];
                NSString *path = [description substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(first.location + first.length, second.location - (first.location + first.length))];
                [idList addObject:path];
            }
        }];
    }        
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
    }
  ];
});
```

At this point, if i log the path of the images i'm receiving this: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG", that for what i know isn't the entire path with the exactly position of the image. Are you ok? So, how can i obtain the entire path of the asset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not retrieving the URL properly from the asset description.

Consider using ALAsset valueForProperty: to ease your task.

```
NSURL *url = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL];
```

You can later use the url to retrieve the asset from the library by using ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:

```
[library assetForURL:self.url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Comment: thanks for help. I have used this code: "NSString *path = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL]". The "absoluteString" isn't recognized. With a log it return to me: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=168BA548-9C81-4B08-B69C-B775E5DD9341&ext=JPG". Is this the complete URL? I don't know, i was expecting something like: "folder1/folder2/anotherFolder/image.jpg". In fact i don't know what mean the id number. Any idea?

Comment: It is not the actual filesystem url since you cannot get it because of sandboxing. Instead the API gives you a proxy url with the above format.

Comment: Thanks again. But at this point i have a new question. How can i use proxy url in my case?

Comment: I do not know what you want to do with the url. I have updated the answer with a sample to retrieve the asset from the url later on in case you need it.